# how to check wheather the slave start replication with the master and what is the status of replication? how much it is completed using mysql db?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp, replication, master-slave

my question is how can i able to know when the slave starts replication with the master and when the slave complete the replication. I want to find out the progress of replication.
when it is started, how much it got progress, and when it went out complete.
Is there any way to find out the time when replication start and time when it will be ended? 
i m using MySQL database available in xampp. How can i detect the start of the replication event beacuse i want to perform some action based on that event. like i want to show the progress bar of how much the replication has been done. thanks in advance

Comment: Have you looked at `SHOW SLAVE STATUS`?

Comment: it does't give me any indication. what is the state of replication how much percent it has been done. also this command don't give me indication about when the replication starts and when the replication completes.

Comment: Replication never completes, it is an ongoing process ...

Comment: Is it possible that you are mixing up the terms 'replication' and 'backup' or 'dump'?

Answer (score 0):

Replication is an ongoing process so "when it started" and "when it will be ended" don't really make sense in this context.

What you can can tell from the `Seconds behind Master` column in the `SHOW SLAVE STATUS` output though is how far behind master changes a slave currently is. You can't really predict how long it will take to catch up with the master, even if the master doesn't produce any further change events, from that value alone, you can just have a rough guess from observing how fast `Seconds behind master` goes down over time.

Especially when using `STATEMENT` based replication (`binlog_format=STATEMENT`) seconds behind master can go up and down quite a bit as replicating a single statement may take quite a while (e.g. `UPDATE` with complex `WHERE` condition). While the statement gets executed you'll see `Seconds behind Master` going up, then again after the statement ends it may suddenly go down to zero again right away if there are no further events in the replication scheme. With `ROW` based replication format this is less of an issue ...

Comment: sir actually i want to know some indication of the when the replication event starts, beacuse i want to perform some action based on that event. how can i detect the start of that event??

Comment: So you want to check for general replication state? Then you need to check for "does SHOW SLAVE STATUS show anything at all?" -> if no then replication has never been set up on that instance. And next for the "Slave_IO_Running" and "Slave_SQL_Running" fields in the output ...

Comment: @Sanaullah Replication starts as soon as a change is made to the database on the master server.